# Unexpected Result Each Time

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I have been trying to implement the Fibonacci series in linear time. I keep getting weird results each time I run the program. I am a newbie in C++.

```
int fib1(int n) {

    int arr[n];
    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];

    }

    return arr[n];
}

int main() {

    int x = fib1(3);
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is: 2

The result I am getting is: 4199748

Where did I mess up?

Comment: for (int i = 2; **i < n**; i++) {

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean?

Comment: `int arr[n]` is not valid C++  (VLAs are a feature of C, and not standard C++).   And, if `arr` is an array with `n` elements,  `return arr[n]` returns the value of a non-existent element, and causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `arr` is of length `n` it doesn't have an element with index `n` and therefore you are accessing the array out-of-bounds in `return arr[n]`. That causes undefined behavior and anything could happen. You probably wanted an array of length `n+1` and iteration up to `i <= n`.

Furthermore the array size must be known at compile time in standard C++. Therefore the variable-length array `arr[n]` is only allowed because your compiler has special support for it. Use `std::vector` instead.